# How does the OS know which device driver to call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I've been `open`ing and `write/read`ing from files/device files and reading up on Operating Systems all this time, but never understood the flow of how a device driver is inevitably called.

For example when we do a `write` to `stdout` which is `fd=1`.
When I do the `write` I understand that the OS calls the device driver for this specific device file that's already open, but what I don't understand is how we get to the device driver itself.

---

1. What is required for the device file (i.e. `stdout`) to even be created in the first place? Mounting? Kernel module loading?
2. (Followup to [1]) So if I have a peripheral device such as a single LED light that's attached to my computer with the correct device drivers for the LED already installed and the device file created in `/dev/singleled`, what happens when I call `open` to `/dev/singleled`?

(Specifically)

- How does the OS know which device driver to call for this device file when I call `write` to it?
- Are we storing information within the file descriptor when we do an `open` on this device file?

---

I really want to understand how this setup is created.
Thank to everyone in advance

Comment: I know this is a long question and I am alright with downvote received, as long as there is someone who can point me to the right direction to see the overall picture of what I've asked

Answer (score 2):

In very brief overview terms, *device nodes* are identified by major and minor numbers which you can see with a command like `ls -l` and would need to be passed to a command like `mknod` if creating them from userspace.

On the kernel side, a driver can register itself for a range of these numbers.

The problem then reduces to managing a modest sized table of association data and using that to look up the appropriate driver and methods registered to handle userspace calls.

You also mentioned LEDs however these are instead usually handled as `sysfs` nodes, ie `/sys/class/LED/xxx` which is a distinct interface that operates by matching names instead of major/minor numbers.

You would probably find it helpful to actually look at a few devices, both their present as nodes in `/dev` or `/sys` and the associated kernel code.  Sample/tutorial drivers written to explain the concepts may be among the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

In the field of *embedded system* (where I work) the OS kernel knows which device driver to call by reading the *Device Tree*. Read [here](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf) to have an idea of what I am speaking about.

However, to be more precise, the Device Tree (that is a file that describes the hardware where the OS will run) is read at booting time. Thus the OS, reading it, will instantiate the right driver. In the field `compatible` of the device tree, there is the exact **key-word** that MUST match with the keyword of the driver.

For example, let's say that you have a Device Tree with this nodes:

```
  ps7_axi_interconnect_0: axi@0 {
#address-cells = <1>;
#size-cells = <1>;
compatible = "xlnx,ps7-axi-interconnect-1.00.a", "simple-bus";
ranges ;
gic: interrupt-controller@f8f01000 {
  #interrupt-cells = < 3 >;
  compatible = "arm,cortex-a9-gic";
  interrupt-controller ;
  reg = < 0xf8f01000 0x1000  >,< 0xf8f00100 0x100  >;
} ;
pl310: pl310-controller@f8f02000 {
  arm,data-latency = < 3 2 2 >;
  arm,tag-latency = < 2 2 2 >;
  cache-level = < 2 >;
  cache-unified ;
  compatible = "arm,pl310-cache";
  interrupts = < 0 34 4 >;
  reg = < 0xf8f02000 0x1000 >;
} ;

  [ ... more items ... ]

xillybus_0: xillybus@50000000 {
  compatible = "xlnx,xillybus-1.00.a";
  reg = < 0x50000000 0x1000 >;
  interrupts = < 0 59 1 >;
  interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
  xlnx,max-burst-len = <0x10>;
  xlnx,native-data-width = <0x20>;
  xlnx,slv-awidth = <0x20>;
  xlnx,slv-dwidth = <0x20>;
  xlnx,use-wstrb = <0x1>;
} ;
```

} ;

Please note the field `compatible`.
Now, the driver that will use this node MUST have something like this:

```
static struct of_device_id xillybus_of_match[] __devinitdata = {
  { .compatible = "xlnx,xillybus-1.00.a", },
  {}
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, xillybus_of_match);
/********something else*******/
static struct platform_driver xillybus_platform_driver = {
  .probe = xilly_drv_probe,
  .remove = xilly_drv_remove,
  .driver = {
    .name = "xillybus",
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .of_match_table = xillybus_of_match,
  },
};
```

To have a better idea of what is going on, please refer to [this](http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1) simple tutorial. I hope this can help.

### About the LED example

In this [git repository folder](https://github.com/leos313/ldd3_training/tree/master/CHAPTER_09/LED_01) you can find a device driver module that, reading the `compatible` field of the device tree, can manage to turn on and of it. In the same folder, there are the source C files to test the driver turning it on and off. You can understand, going through the C code, what is happening when `open` and `close` are called and so on.

Comment: Not everything is Device Tree.

Comment: Actually this is not answering the question, which is about the link between a device file in `/dev` and a driver: how the kernel handle this link?
The answer here is more about the matching between a device instance and a driver (which may not have any file in `/dev`) in the very narrow case of device tree (which is excluding, for example, all the plug'n'play world: PCI, USB, FireWire, ...)